# How to make side menu with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to make the pink element at the left and all the other needs to be right side `width: calc(100% - 250px)` just like the image shows

[image]

**The reason why I use `display: flex` I need to use `order` for mobile and tablet devices**. I have been trying with the properties of `flex-basis` but unfortunately none my tricks are not working

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
body > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 calc(100% - 250px);
  -ms-flex: 1 calc(100% - 250px);
  flex: 1 calc(100% - 250px);
  padding: 10px;
}
header {
  background: tomato;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}
section {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
}
aside {
  background: hotpink;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 250px;
  -ms-flex: 1 250px;
  flex: 1 250px;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  ordeR: 4;
}
```

```html
<header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam provident at, itaque ea quia. Quaerat accusamus ex reprehenderit harum nulla quis ipsam maxime necessitatibus atque cupiditate quidem, earum laborum pariatur</header>
<aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, minima excepturi asperiores delectus eaque eligendi, aliquam quos itaque. Eligendi ipsum sapiente inventore, unde consectetur quos aliquam iure ipsam fugit ratione.</aside>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, modi quis vel tempora assumenda corporis quaerat at pariatur suscipit dolores eveniet, delectus deleniti quisquam. Nisi minus, voluptate repudiandae modi laboriosam</section>
<footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit at placeat voluptate distinctio atque aliquam et enim, quam, laudantium, velit molestias earum culpa ipsam. Deleniti totam natus saepe distinctio officia.</footer>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/20fet497/

Comment: What's the layout for mobile / tablet? My answer covers one layout because it was posted before you revised your question.

Comment: @Michael_B As simple as the solution looking for using `order` properties in `display: flex`. The reson behind editing the question is some people are misunderstanding the question that is why edited.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this layout with a nested flex container set to `column` direction:

**HTML**

```
<aside>aside</aside>
<div id="inner-flex-container">
    <header>header</header>
    <section>section</section>
    <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ */
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit; /* https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex; /* body is the outer flex container */
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner-flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

aside   { flex: 1 250px; background: hotpink; }
header  { flex: 1; background: tomato; }
section { flex: 4; background: deepskyblue; }
footer  { flex: 1; background: lightgreen; }
```

The code above creates this responsive, flexible layout (and it's all [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/)):

[image]

[**DEMO 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/20fet497/1/)

---

***Adjusting layout for mobile / tablet devices***

With the HTML above, the `order` property can still be used to re-arrange flex items:

**CSS** (added the order property and media query)

```
html {
     height: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box; /* https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ */
}

*, *:before, *:after {
     box-sizing: inherit; /* https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex; /* body is the outer flex container */
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    text-align: center;
}

#inner-flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: calc(100% - 250px);
   order: 1;
}

aside   { flex: 1 250px; order: 0; background: hotpink; }
header  { flex: 1; order: 0; background: tomato; }
section { flex: 4; order: 1; background: deepskyblue; }
footer  { flex: 1; order: 2; background: lightgreen; }

@media screen and ( max-width: 500px) {
     body { flex-direction: column; }
     aside { flex: 1; order: 2; }
     #inner-flex-container { width: 100%; flex: 1; }
}
```

[image]

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/20fet497/3/)

Using `order`, one block of flex items – `aside` and `#inner-flex-container` – can be re-arranged.

A second block of flex items – `header`, `section` and `footer` – can also be re-arranged.

The only limitation to `order` in this case would be if you wanted to re-arrange `aside` within the `#inner-flex-container` block.

---

*(Of course, life being what it is, you've revised your question to say this limitation is exactly what you need :-)*

---

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually the purpose of `display:flex` is using order which doesn't possible to apply with the answer

Comment: `order` can still be used. It depends on the mobile / tablet layout you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution doing exactly what you asked, with your structure kept and a media query to re-position the `aside` when screen gets bigger.

Edit: Second version, using flex and media query.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
body > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 0;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

aside {
  flex: 0;
  background: hotpink;
}

footer {
  flex: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
}

@media screen and ( min-width: 500px) {  
  body {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
  aside {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 150px;
    order: 1;
  }
  header,
  section,
  footer {
    order: 2;
    width: calc(100% - 150px);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<aside>Aside</aside>
<section>Section</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

---

First version, where I used position absolute and flex.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  position: relative;
}
body > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

header {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 0;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
}

aside {
  flex: 0;
  background: hotpink;
}

footer {
  flex: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
}

@media screen and ( min-width: 500px) {
    aside {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 150px
    }
    header,
    section,
    footer {
      margin-left: 150px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>Header</header>
<aside>Aside</aside>
<section>Section</section>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually try to mix kind of a mix of row and column layout. wich flex does not do. But flex boxes can be inbricated, and that will do.

you should not use flex for aside , but height and set height to body (not min-height), from there you can wrap your columns and draw 2 of them in one row.

But the fixed height won't allow body to grow taller and html to scroll, unless you overide this and update body's height via javascript ... if inbrication is really not an option.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;/*maybe  not min-height but height usable for aside */
  /* beside, i guess IE will get it via height */
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  
}

header {
  background: tomato;
  order: 2;
  flex:1;
}
section {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  order: 3;
  width:calc(100% - 250px);/* remove here width of aside , px, %, vw, whatever value used */
  flex:4;/* or more, or less, depends how much you want header/footer to shrink when everything is empty or small contents */
}
aside {
  background: hotpink;
  height:100%;
  width:250px;
  order:1;
  /* no flex values here, just use height */
}
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  order: 4;
  flex:1;
}
body>* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:10px;
  /* add X,Y center
  display:flex;
  font-size:4vw;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center; */
  }
```

```html
<header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam provident at, itaque ea quia. Quaerat accusamus ex reprehenderit harum nulla quis ipsam maxime necessitatibus atque cupiditate quidem, earum laborum pariatur</header>
<aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, minima excepturi asperiores delectus eaque eligendi, aliquam quos itaque. Eligendi ipsum sapiente inventore, unde consectetur quos aliquam iure ipsam fugit ratione.</aside>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, modi quis vel tempora assumenda corporis quaerat at pariatur suscipit dolores eveniet, delectus deleniti quisquam. Nisi minus, voluptate repudiandae modi laboriosam</section>
<footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit at placeat voluptate distinctio atque aliquam et enim, quam, laudantium, velit molestias earum culpa ipsam. Deleniti totam natus saepe distinctio officia.</footer>
```

[DEMO to play with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrKPm)

To allow `aside` to be rezized , you may use `max-width` and `min-width`  *(see snippet below)*

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background: tomato;
  order: 2;
  flex: 1;
}
section {
  text-align: left;
  background: deepskyblue;
  order: 3;
  flex: 4;
  /* or more, or less, depends how much you want header/ffoter to shrink when everything is empty or small contents */
}
header,
section,
footer {
  width: calc(100% - 20%);
  /* that's about aside's width */
  max-width: calc(100% - 150px);
  /* keep room for aside's min-width */
  overflow: auto;
}
aside {
  background: hotpink;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 150px;
  /* keep it not smaller than */
  width: 20%;
  /* don let it grow more than */
  order: 1;
}
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  order: 4;
  flex: 1;
}
body>* {
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nam provident at, itaque ea quia. Quaerat accusamus ex reprehenderit harum nulla quis ipsam maxime necessitatibus atque cupiditate quidem, earum laborum pariatur</header>
<aside>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, minima excepturi asperiores delectus eaque eligendi, aliquam quos itaque. Eligendi ipsum sapiente inventore, unde consectetur quos aliquam iure ipsam fugit ratione.</aside>
<section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, modi quis vel tempora assumenda corporis quaerat at pariatur suscipit dolores eveniet, delectus deleniti quisquam. Nisi minus, voluptate repudiandae modi laboriosam</section>
<footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit at placeat voluptate distinctio atque aliquam et enim, quam, laudantium, velit molestias earum culpa ipsam. Deleniti totam natus saepe distinctio officia.</footer>
```

Comment: this is kind of solution is I am looking for the solution. unfortunately there is width issue when add contents with in the elements  https://jsfiddle.net/4p4dkq05/

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil not too sure what you meant, see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxrKPm (second example + your content + overflow on section to keep footer on sight)

Comment: In small screen overflowing the content to `overflow-x`

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil we en are ending with an horrible frameset like page http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoqKWw Actually, flex is not adapted here, because you need inheritance of height to size aside. Flex works fine for rows or columns, but not a mixed of them (wrapping columns ... to draw a row need an height set ;) )

Comment: I have just uploaded mobile structure image with the desktop one. `aside` needs to come inside the other elements that is the reason I am trying to use `order`. I appreciated for your effort  hope there will be solution 

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil okay, i see, actually for mobile flex and sizing is not required, it is only block elements :)

Comment: you are right, take a my updated snippet please  http://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/gPMYxq

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil have considered mediaqueries ?to reset a few rules below a certain width  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMWwrL i'll delete this answer in a few minutes . good luck

Comment: something wrong gone on my code, I will update ASAP. Yes, I need to use `order` in `mediaquery`

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil okay so it would be a reset on heights/widths and orders to send aside all the way down : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPMYvE

Comment: or http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGXbmj reset on width/max-width with calc() (for version where the aside width is being resized ).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```css
* { 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-flow: column wrap;

  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
  width: calc(100% - 15%);
}

.aside {
  background: hotpink;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 15%;
}

.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: calc(100% - 15%);
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: calc(100% - 15%);
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .header {
    order: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .aside {
    order: 2;
    -webkit-flex-basis: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .main {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .footer {
    order: 4;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <aside class="aside">Aside</aside>
  <header class="header">Header</header>
  <article class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, modi
      quis vel tempora assumenda corporis quaerat at pariatur suscipit 
      dolores eveniet, delectus deleniti quisquam. Nisi minus, voluptate 
      repudiandae modi laboriosam.
    </p>  
  </article>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

You should use float: right and float: left, and accordingly add width and height.
Example could look like this:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: tomato;
  height: 20%;
  float: right;
  width: 85%;
}
section {
  height: 60%;
  width: 85%;
  background: deepskyblue;
  float: right;
}
aside {
  background: hotpink;
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
footer {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 85%;
  height: 20%;
  float: right;
}
```