# li a:focus, Prevent Focus Loss when i click in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i prevent my `ul.SideNav_Main li a:focus` class, loss the focus when i'm click on the iframe or other place in the page? Wasn't supposed as `a:focus` it keeps forever focus until i click in other URL of the list?

It's possible to solve with pure CSS? Or maybe with some JavaScript code?

**My CSS:**

```
ul.SideNav_Main {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ebf6f9;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul.SideNav_Main li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2e849e;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
}


ul.SideNav_Main li a:focus:not(.Active):not(.Logout) {
    background-color: #ffdb99;
}

ul.SideNav_Main ul.SideNav_Sub {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<ul class="SideNav_Main">
    <li><a class="Active" href="yPage.php?ID=30000" target="_iframe">HOME</a></li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">RaspLot</a>
        <ul class="SideNav_Sub" id="T101">
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10101" target="_iframe">Controlo Diário</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10102" target="_iframe">Balanços</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10103" target="_iframe">Consultar Artigos</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10104" target="_iframe">Inserir Artigos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Segurança</a>
        <ul class="SideNav_Sub" id="T301">
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=30101" target="_iframe">Alterar Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=30102" target="_iframe">Alterar eKey</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Master</a>
        <ul class="SideNav_Sub" id="T398">
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39801" target="_iframe">Registry Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39802" target="_iframe">Registry Alert</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39803" target="_iframe">Explorer SSID</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39899" target="_iframe">Print_r</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a class="Logout" href="yPage.php?ID=39900" target="_parent">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

[When i Click gets `focus`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpRPz.jpg)

[When i Click in other place of page, it losses `focus`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ9oX.jpg)

Comment: You can have only one focused element at any time, but if you need to focus on other elements and keep the previous one looks focused you need to think about another approach, maybe you can use `visited` instead of `focus`? if this doesn't achieve what you need, you can consider adding/removing styles from JavaScript (ie. on click give it the needed style ( background color in this case), and reset the style for other elements if exists)

Comment: I need to get focus on the last url that i clicked, and keep it while i work on my iframe on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

The `:focus` pseudo-class is used to style elements as long as it has received focus, either by clicking on it or using the `tab` key. As soon as you click somewhere else or use the `tab` key to navigate, the previously focused element loses focus.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus

To highlight the active page, give it a css class (eg. `.current-page`) and give it some extra styling:

```css
ul.SideNav_Main {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ebf6f9;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul.SideNav_Main li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2e849e;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display: block;
}


ul.SideNav_Main li a.current-page:not(.Active):not(.Logout) {
    background-color: #ffdb99;
}

ul.SideNav_Main ul.SideNav_Sub {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="SideNav_Main">
    <li><a class="Active" href="yPage.php?ID=30000" target="_iframe">HOME</a></li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">RaspLot</a>
        <ul class="SideNav_Sub" id="T101">
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10101" target="_iframe">Controlo Diário</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10102" target="_iframe" class="current-page">Balanços</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10103" target="_iframe">Consultar Artigos</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=10104" target="_iframe">Inserir Artigos</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Segurança</a>
        <ul class="SideNav_Sub" id="T301">
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=30101" target="_iframe">Alterar Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=30102" target="_iframe">Alterar eKey</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">Master</a>
        <ul class="SideNav_Sub" id="T398">
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39801" target="_iframe">Registry Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39802" target="_iframe">Registry Alert</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39803" target="_iframe">Explorer SSID</a></li>
            <li><a href="yPage.php?ID=39899" target="_iframe">Print_r</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a class="Logout" href="yPage.php?ID=39900" target="_parent">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for my. I need to keep my last li clicked Alive while i work on the iframe o the rightside.

Comment: You'd have to use JavaScript (or any js framework) to catch click events and set the `current-page` class. That may be hard using iFrames, but they are a very outdated way of frontend design. I'd reccomend you to redesign your page to use [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380985/how-to-make-side-menu-with-flexbox) to see how to do that.